# Full screen cookie banner on mobile, is it a bad or good approach?

Tags: usability, interaction-design, cookies

I am developing a cookie banner for a company. The designer presented all the mockups, but I am not convinced whether it should be full-screen on mobile. The advantage is that the user might be seeing all the banner text at the same time, but you are forcing him to see that instead of the website he intended to visit. On the other hand, a half-width cookie banner is having the lorem ipsum text having to be scrolled down, which is also not optimal

[image]

Comment: "Cookie walls that make consent conditional for access to a website is likewise non-compliant. Consent is not allowed to be forced in return of website access." - If you're aiming to be GDPR compliant, the current design is not the way to go, regardless of UX considerations.

Comment: thanks @Duroth You can answer this in a post comment and I will accept your answer, which was rather useful, thanks!

Comment: Cookie Banners are creepy as hell...  Who the hell suggested that forcing users to accept something without other choices is better than not showing it?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to clarify which cookies are used for what purpose. This is why, even if the wall of toggles looks like crap, it is required for people to understand what's being requested of them and what data is stored.

Otherwise, in a lawsuit, a person may claim they were not informed and invoke fraudulent intent (by hiding the usage) which would have grounds for approval in a court of law.

This approach, although elegant, hides that information, and, like Duroth mentioned, conditions access to information.

Answer (score 0):

Make it small, with 1 sentence, and a link to learn more. Find out what the real content is before you design around needing full screen.